# Get easy_install to work with more recent version of Python

Tags: python, setuptools, easy-install

`Python 2.4` was the default on my `CentOS5` system. I now have `Python 2.6` running and I am trying to do an `easy_install`.

I installed the setuptools egg file for Python 2.6.  `py26` is on `username.sitename.com` while `python 2.4` is installed system wide so I currently just get a permission denied error when i run

```
easy_install mysqldb
```

because it is trying to modify the 2.4 installation.

How do I get this to work with Python 2.6 in my subdomain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `easy_install` has the option of specifying the Python version to use a la:

```
easy_install-N.N
```

So in this case I just do `easy_install-2.6`

Should have looked it up more closely before posting!

[using easy-install](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall#using-easy-install)

Answer (score 1):

You can also force Python interpreter to run easy_install.

```
 python2.6 /usr/bin/easy_install foobar
```

You can also try to break your system by upgrading easy_install version itself (old versions of easy_install a.k.a setuptools are bug ridden)

```
 python2.6 /usr/bin/easy_install -U setuptools
```

Note that each easy_install hosts different data for each Python interpreter

Comment: Acutally  easy-install-2.7 was not enough for me, I had to specify the python2. Thanks Mikko

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this might be a good use-case for [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html), which lets you easily manage switching between and isolating multiple Python environments. Use the `--python` switch to specify the path to your desired python version, e.g.:

```
$ virtualenv --python /path/to/python2.6 env_name
...
$ source env_name/bin/activate
(env_name)$ which python
/path/to/env_name/bin/easy_install
(env_name)$ which easy_install
/path/to/env_name/bin/easy_install
(env_name)$ deactivate
$ which python
/path/to/system/python
```